# Is there WindowTabs like app on Mac OS X?

Tags: software-recommendation, applications, window-manager

On Windows, I love to use an app called [WindowsTabs](http://www.windowtabs.com/).

> WindowTabs runs in the background and attaches a tab to each of your application windows. Drag one tab onto another and create a tabbed group. By organizing your windows into logically related groups, you can more easily manage a large number of open windows.

I searched google for Mac equivalent, but got nothing so far.

Does anyone know a similar app?

Comment: Could please explain briefly what the app does or what the feature you're looking for are?  It'll be easier for people to find apps.

Answer (score 2):

[StickyWindows](http://www.donelleschi.com/stickywindows/) creates a tab for every window that sits on the desktop. Its not exactly what WindowsTabs do but it is something ;)
It seems to only work with Leopard though :(

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac, each app has it's own major window, and it's up to the App developer to allow tabs. Many already do.

One app that doesn't is Finder. There is an inexpensive app that adds tab functions to Finder, [TotalFinder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/).

This may help a bit.

Comment: I think he wants to group independant apps, not have tabs in one specific app.

Answer (score 0):

OS X comes with ways to manage many open windows: Exposé, Spaces, and Mission Control. These, along with the fact that most Mac users don't maximize windows, generally obviates the need for third-party window management apps.

If you need to group windows from various apps, toss each group into its own Space.